# Sitecore asp.net Edit Custom User Profile Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7

I have a field on a user profile that corresponds to an id in another system. I want to set this when a user visits an activation link. After registering the user in the other system, I add a role and set their membership approval to true. I was getting an error saying that I cannot set the property of an anonymous user so I moved where I was assigning the id after the role/activation piece however I still got the same error.

```
private bool SetCustomId(string username, Guid id)
{

    var userProfile = ((User)User.FromName(username, AccountType.User)).Profile;
    userProfile.SetCustomProperty("MyIdField", id.ToString());
    userProfile.Save();//error thrown here
}
```

User profile is what I would expect and when I moved it after the piece that assigned the user a role, they did have the role I expected them to.

Here's the actual exception: `This property cannot be set for anonymous users.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `User.FromName(username, true)` instead.  The boolean parameter tells it to treat the user as authenticated.

Comment: Hmm alright. That makes sense based solely on the error message. Any idea why I couldn't set any properties after giving the user a role/enabling them? I'm assuming authenticated is the same as enabled which may be wrong. Maybe authenticated means online/currently logged in or something along those lines.

Comment: Yes, authenticated means logged in.  If the IsAuthenticated flag is not set on the user, the underlying role provider assumes that the user is anonymous.  By default, profile properties cannot be set on anonymous users.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the user, try the following code:

```
userProfile.Initialize(username, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
private bool SetCustomId(string username, Guid id)
{
    using(new Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(username,false));)
    {
        var userProfile = ((User)User.FromName(username, AccountType.User)).Profile;
        userProfile.SetCustomProperty("MyIdField", id.ToString());
        userProfile.Save();
    }

}
```